# Accessing the actual value of a RadGrid DataItem rather than its text

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid, radgrid

I have a `RadGrid` with `AutoGenerate` columns set to `true`.

My datasource looks like the following:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Column1", typeof (double));
dt.Columns.Add("Column2", typeof (double));
dt.Columns.Add("Column3", typeof (double));

dt.Rows.Add(0.05547, 0.03432, 0.03444);
dt.Rows.Add(0.54612, 0.77764, 0.86763);
dt.Rows.Add(0.65711, 0.88735, 0.67864);
```

In the grids `ItemDataBound` event I am formatting the values to be percents like this:

```
double number;
if (double.TryParse(item[col.UniqueName].Text, out number))
{
     item[col.UniqueName].Text = string.Format("{0:P2}", number);                            
}
```

Now lets say I want to loop through the grid `DataItems` somewhere else in the code and get the original values, not the formatted percent values. What is the best way to do this?

```
foreach (GridDataItem item in RadGrid1.Items) 
{
     // This is returning a value like 5 %, I need 0.05547
     item["Column1"].Text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are formatting the text in `ItemDataBound`, you cannot get the original value somewhere else in the code. `ItemDataBound` is a behaviour, so each time when you do postback `ItemDatabound` will be executed, (even for changing the page size in radgrid).

But you can do it, by  Creating a new `datatable` and filling those details parallely in `ItemDataBound`. So you can get the data from that datatable throughout your code.

Comment: I just ended up adding a new row to my datatable that isn't formatted in the ItemDataBound. When I go an retrieve the original values I pull from that row rather than the formatted one.